# como puedo bloquear las fechas pasadas de un input de tipo date en jsp

Tags: jquery

quiero un ejemplo similar como notan los dias atras del dias 9 estan bloqueados yo quiero una paresido pero con la fecha actual espero aver explicado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Debes saber que lo primero es poner el código que has escrito para resolver el problema. De lo contrario no podrán ayudarte y puede que la pregunta reciba votos negativos.